# Xcode UI Test cannot access multiple collection views inside a table view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitest

I have a problem with accessing collection view cells inside a table view cell when using `app.debugDescription` during XCode UI Test runs.

First of all, `XCUIApplication` proxy do not see any collection views, but there are 4 of them, 2nd it does not see any cells other than the 4 cells of UITableView.

I have tried setting `isAccessibilityIdentifier` to `false` on these table view cells, but no use. If I set `isAccessibilityIdentifier` to `true` for each collection view, then I can see 4 collection views, but still no cells. I have put `accessibilityIdentifier` values to each cell in collection view and on elements inside a collection view, like `UILabel` and `UIImageView`.

If I set `isAccessibilityIdentifier` to `true` for collection view cells, then I can see `accessibilityIdentifiers` for each cell when printing out `app.debugDescription`, but as other element, not as of cell type.

Can anyone assist me here, here is my screenshot of view hierarchy in the storyboard.

[image]